# How to json-schema could validate a property as declared OR alternative structure (to delete it)

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I trying to optimize data transfer.

So what I want is to have a normal schema declaration like:

```
{
 properties:{
   "id":{"type":"integer"}
   ,"prop1":{.....}
   ,"propN":{.....}
   ,"propArray":{"type":"array", "items":{"type":"object":"properties":{.....}}}
 }
}
```

But the schema should also validate something like:

```
{
"prop6":{"__action__":"delete"}
,"prop7":{"prop7_1":{"prop7_1_1":{"__action__":"delete"}}}
,"propArray":[{"__keyX__":{"__action__":"delete"}}, {"__keyY__":{"__action__":"delete"}}]
}
```

Please consider that:

- actual schemas are more complex and nested
- the schemas must be builded starting from a repository (so I have to write code to write code to obtain this result)

Any Ideas?

I'm trying with a more simple schema using anyOf but it is invalid:

```
{
  "$id": "https://json-schema.hyperjump.io/schema",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema"
,   "properties":  {  
        "num":{ "anyOf":[
            {"type":"integer"}
        ,   {"type":"object"
                ,"properties":  {
                        "action":{"enum":["delete","add"]}
                    ,   "value":{"type":"integer"}

                }
                ,   "additionalProperties": false
                , "required":["action","value"]

             }

      ]
   }
    ,   "unevaluatedProperties": true
    ,   "additionalProperties": false
    ,   "required": ["num"]

}
```

Another approach could be:

```
{
    "$id": "https://doclc/schema1",
      "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
    "$defs": {
        "deleteEnabled": {
            "properties": {
                "__keyToDelete__": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "pattern": "^\\w+(\\[\\d+\\])?(\\.\\w+(\\[\\d+\\])?)?$"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "deleteRequired": {
            "required": [
                "__keyToDelete__"
            ]
        },
        "normalRequired": {
            "required": [
                "num"
            ]
        }
    },
    "allOf": [
        {
            "if": {

                "properties": {"__action__": {"enum": ["update","delete"]   }}
                    
            },
            "then": {
                
                    "$ref": "#/$defs/deleteEnabled"
                
            }
        },
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "__action__": {
                        "const": "delete"
                    }
                }
            },
            "else": {
                
              
              "$ref": "#/$defs/normalRequired"
            },
            "then": {
                
              "$ref": "#/$defs/deleteRequired"
            }
        }
    ],
    "properties": {
        "num": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "__action__": {
            "enum": [
                "delete",
                "add",
                "update"
            ]
        },
        "__keyToDelete1__": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "^\\w+(\\[\\d+\\])?(\\.\\w+(\\[\\d+\\])?)?$"
            }
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "unevaluatedProperties": false
}
```

In other world I want to foresee __keyToDelete only if **action** is update or delete; and set it to required only if **action** is delete.

But the simple:

```
 {
  "num": 5
}
```

Catch the second "if then"

The jb:

```
{
        "num":          5
  ,      "__action__":"update"
  , "__keyToDelete__":["a"]
    
}
```

doen't catch the first "if-then" and I recieve: Property '**keyToDelete**' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties.